# Why is the distance between two points in a 2d plane not differentiable when the distance is 0?

Tags: calculus

I've been told that if we have two moving points in a 2d plane, their movement described by:

$$x_{1}(t) = v_{x1}\times t + x_{1_{0}}, 0 <= t < t_{end}$$
$$y_{1}(t) = v_{y1}\times t + y_{1_{0}}, 0 <= t < t_{end}$$

and analogously for $y_{2}(t)$ and $x_{2}(t)$, then, if we write the distance between them as:

$$D(t) = \sqrt{(v_{x1}\times t + x_{1_{0}}-v_{x_{2}} \times t-x_{2_{0}})^2+(v_{y_{1}}\times t + y_{1_{0}}-v_{y_{2}} \times t-y_{2_{0}})^2}$$,

then D(t) is not differentiable when the distance is zero. Why is this?

Comment: It's not even true in one dimension!

Comment: For the same reason it is not differentiable in one dimension.

Comment: Why isn't it differentiable in one dimension then? I've plotted it and I see the sharp edge in the origin, but I can't *understand* why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance (in $1$ dimension) behaves like $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ and it is well-known, that the function $f:\mathbf R \to \mathbf R$, $x\mapsto |x|$ is not differentiable in $0$. Just calculate $f_+'(0)$ and $f_-'(0)$.